# WPF: Radial Gradient as Mouse Moves Over a Control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2008, gradient

I want to apply a radial gradient effect to my buttons as mouse moves over them as explained [here](https://wpf.2000things.com/2011/02/27/230-changing-a-radial-gradient-as-mouse-moves-over-a-control/). So I have a separated resource file where I define my buttons style.

**MyButtonStyle.xaml**:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyTestButtons">
    <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="MyButtonStyle">
        <!--<Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />-->
        <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">                   
                    <Border  Name="Border" CornerRadius="0"  
                             BorderBrush="#000" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" 
                             Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" 
                                          ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" 
                                          Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" 
                                          HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" 
                                          Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
                                          VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}" />
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

And I apply to my buttons as below.

**Window**:

```
<Window x:Class="MyTestButtons"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary  Source="/MyButtonStyle.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>

   <Button Name="btnYes" Content="Yes"  
        Margin="3,5" MinWidth="70" Height="35" 
        Click="Button_Click" Foreground="Black" FontSize="14" 
        Style="{StaticResource MyButtonStyle}"  
         VerticalAlignment="Center" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  
        VerticalContentAlignment="Center" 
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" 
        MouseMove="btnYes_MouseMove" 
        MouseLeave="btnYes_MouseLeave">
    <Button.Background>
        <RadialGradientBrush x:Name="gradRadial" RadiusX="0.25">
            <GradientStop Color="AliceBlue" Offset="0.0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="LightSteelBlue" Offset="1.0"/>
        </RadialGradientBrush>
    </Button.Background>
   </Button>
</Window>
```

**Window code-behind**:

```
    private void btnYes_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Point pt = Mouse.GetPosition(btnYes);
        gradRadial.GradientOrigin = new Point(pt.X / btnYes.Width, pt.Y / btnYes.Height);
        gradRadial.Center = gradRadial.GradientOrigin;
    }

    private void btnYes_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        gradRadial.GradientOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);   // Default
        gradRadial.Center = gradRadial.GradientOrigin;
    }
```

My problems and goals are:

1. Radial gradient is not being applied correctly. I mean, the radial gradient is shown in the center of my button without putting mouse over and while mouse moves over the button, the radial gradient always stays at the center, radial gradient is not generated from the origin where my mouse is over like in the screenshot of the three mouse shown in the [link](https://wpf.2000things.com/2011/02/27/230-changing-a-radial-gradient-as-mouse-moves-over-a-control/) provided.
2. Using code behind forces me two create two events, MouseMove and MouseLeave for each button. I would like to do it without code behind, only using xaml and put all the code in one file, just in my style file MyButtonStyle.xaml.

Comment: I think the answer to issue #1 is found in the link you provided.  Note this important detail `We also need to disable the default rendering of the button while the mouse is over it.  We can do this by changing the RenderMouseOver property of the ButtonChrome object–found in the button’s control template–to False.`

Comment: @pstrjds ok I have done. Now, how can I disable the default rendering of the button while the mouse is over it in my style file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fisrt problem happens because of this:

```
gradRadial.GradientOrigin = new Point(pt.X / btnYes.Width, pt.Y / btnYes.Height);
```

You use `btnYes.Width` but you don't set this property for your button, and by default it has not defined value (`double.NaN`), so you end up with Point where one component is undefined (whatever that might mean). Instead use

```
gradRadial.GradientOrigin = new Point(pt.X / btnYes.ActualWidth, pt.Y / btnYes.ActualHeight);
```

As for second problem. First, styles can set event handlers via `EventSetter`. Second, resource dictionaries may have code-behind. So you can do this. First assign class to your resource dictionary:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                x:Class="WpfApplication1.Resources">
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Then define code-behind:

```
// this is in namespace WpfApplication1
partial class Resources : ResourceDictionary {
    public Resources() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void OnMyButtonMouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
        var btn = (Button) sender;
        var gradient = btn.Background as RadialGradientBrush;
        if (gradient == null)
            return;
        gradient.GradientOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5); // Default
        gradient.Center = gradient.GradientOrigin;
    }

    private void OnMyButtonMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
        var btn = (Button) sender;
        var gradient = btn.Background as RadialGradientBrush;
        if (gradient == null)
            return;
        Point pt = Mouse.GetPosition(btn);
        gradient.GradientOrigin = new Point(pt.X / btn.ActualWidth, pt.Y / btn.ActualHeight);
        gradient.Center = gradient.GradientOrigin;
    }
}
```

Then assign handlers in style:

```
<Style TargetType="Button"
       x:Key="MyButtonStyle">
    <!-- skipped -->
    <EventSetter Event="MouseLeave" Handler="OnMyButtonMouseLeave"/>
    <EventSetter Event="MouseMove" Handler="OnMyButtonMouseMove"/>
</Style>
```

Comment: IMHO, it would be useful to point out to the OP that, had they simply debugged the `MouseMove` handler and examined the value for the `Point`, they would have immediately seen the `X` value as `NaN`, which should have led them back to the `Width` value also being `NaN` (i.e. the default).

Comment: @PeterDuniho that's true, though I was a bit surprised that this does not result in some exception somewhere along the road (in Point constructor, or while assigning invalid point to GradientOrigin). Though maybe there is some sense in point with undefined coordinates and I just fail to see it.

Comment: @PeterDuniho You are right. But since it was not thrown any exception I supposed that values are ok. I will be careful next time.

Comment: @Evk It wasn't throwing any exception so it was confusing me. Your solution works like a charm! I have marked your answer as the correct. Thx man!